# IE 11, 10, 9 wont display navigation properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I've tried for a long time to get this to fix. The big text navigation is at the top in IE11/10/9, but all other browsers have it placed lower. When you hover over the other nav, IE will push it down in the proper spot.

here is the demo site:
https://xdvn.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm....it seems like adding the height to your secondary nav fixed the issue in IE.

```
#secondary_nav {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 77px;
}
```

I am still trying to wrap my head around it to know why exactly this is happening. It seems like IE doesn't know where the bottom will be for that absolute element until that link is hovered over. So set height for the first nav element will make it behave right.